# OpenLayers clustering -- clustering data doesn't appear in event.feature object

Tags: openlayers

My question is pretty simple -- I'm using Dojo (but not the Dojox openlayers modules) to create a mapping project. I've followed examples right off the web to create little hover bubbles for metadata and for clustering.  I'm currently trying to draw a group of 100+ observations recorded by a sensor (that never moves, so each observation has the same lat/lon).  When the object is selected, the event that fires does not contain the feature.cluster object.  At any zoom level, only the top feature appears and I have no access to any of the other data.   What am I doing wrong?

```
drawObservations: function(data){
                console.info("drawing observatoins", data);

                if (this.observationLayer !== null){
                    this.map.removeLayer(this.observationLayer);
                }
                console.info("building features");
                var features = [];
                for (var i in data.observations){

                    //console.info("working on observation: ", data.observations[i]);
                    var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(data.observations[i].longitude, data.observations[i].latitude);
                    //console.info("point: ", point);


                    features[i] = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point, {
                        id : data.observations[i].id,
                        startTime: data.observations[i].startTime,
                        endTime: data.observations[i].endTime
                    }, {
                        fillColor : '#008040',
                        fillOpacity : 0.8,                    
                        strokeColor : "#ee9900",
                        strokeOpacity : 1,
                        strokeWidth : 1,
                        pointRadius : 8
                    });

                }
                console.info("features size: ", features.length);
                console.info("building vectors");

                this.observationLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Observations", {
                    projection: "EPSG:4326",
                    strategies: [                     
                    new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster()
                    ],
                    eventListeners:{
                        'featureselected':function(evt){
                            console.info("feature selected: ", evt);
                            console.info("this: ", this);
                            var feature = evt.feature;
                            var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("popup",
                                OpenLayers.LonLat.fromString(feature.geometry.toShortString()),
                                null,
                                "<div style='font-size:.8em'><h3>Observation - " + feature.attributes.id + "</h3><hr/><b>Start Time: </b>" + feature.attributes.startTime + "<br/><b>End Time: </b>" + feature.attributes.endTime + "</div>",
                                null,
                                true
                                );
                            feature.popup = popup;
                            this.map.addPopup(popup);
                        },
                        'featureunselected':function(evt){
                            console.info("feature unselected: ", evt);
                            var feature = evt.feature;
                            this.map.removePopup(feature.popup);
                            feature.popup.destroy();
                            feature.popup = null;
                        }
                     }
                });

                console.info("adding features to vector", this.observationLayer);

                this.observationLayer.addFeatures(features);

                this.map.addLayer(this.observationLayer);

                var selector = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(this.observationLayer,{
                    hover:true,
                    autoActivate:true
                }); 
                this.observationLayer.events.on({
                    "featureselected": this.display
                });

                this.map.addControl(selector);
            },

            display: function(event){
                console.info("event: ", event);

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the trick is to remove the features from the layer and re-add them at them after the layer has been added to the map:

```
this.observationLayer.removeFeatures(this.observationLayer.features);
this.observationLayer.addFeatures(features);
```

This make clustering magically work.